# What happened to download optimized images, script and css resources in PageSpeed Insights?

Tags: pagespeed-insights

It looks like PageSpeed Insights got a makeover, and I don't see that you can download optimized images, scripts, and css resources anymore???

Can anyone tell me if i'm missing it? I've looked and looked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the option to download optimized images, scripts, and css resources has been removed in the newer version of pagespeed. Now you need to search online tools that will do the same job.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the GTmetrix site to analyze your website and then download the optimized version of your images just right click on the optimized image and then download for the html css and java script you will need a cache plugin to optimize such as wp fastest cache or wp rocket